# How to upgrade PHP 5.5.30 to PHP7 in XAMPP, Using Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: php, xampp

PHP 7 is released, How can i install PHP7 in XAMPP.
I am currently using PHP 5.5.30 and my Ubuntu version is 15.10 .
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php-7.0) with PHP7:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

Comment: will it work with xamp ?

Comment: I don't know. Try it in a virtual machine.

Comment: nope, it will not work on xampp :)

Answer (score 0):

In the new version lamp-server included php 7. just use the default installation

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server
```

https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Comment: That command would give the following error message: `E: Unable to locate package lamp-server`. The easiest way to fix your command is `sudo apt-get install tasksel  && sudo tasksel install lamp-server`.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I'm aware PHP7 isn't officially included in your version of Ubuntu (not sure about plans for the future) - so you will have to either find some unofficial packages or build your php7 installation yourself.

Comment: PHP7 is not officially included i know that. What i mean is to how to update php in xampp which i installed in ubuntu !

Comment: You should check that then probably with xampp maintainers - if their installation provides PHP7.  Otherwise my answer still stays valid - some unofficial debs or own installation/compilation.